# Android: SMS receiver broadcast intent is triggered by unread sms'es at each reboot / at next SMS in chain

Tags: java, android, sms

A *schrödinbug* appeared on one of my projects, where an Android application reportedly started to behave wrong on S4 running Hangouts (much like in [Android. Error. Pop SMS notification after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160559/android-error-pop-sms-notification-after-reboot)).

I think this may be a common problem; so what are good ideas for filtering duplicate SMS broadcasts on Android?

Comment: *Given the fact the project is SMS-control API for industrial application, and S4 is CIO's phone used to run tests, it was kinda weird to see it locked to continuous reboots issued by unread SMS containing reboot request.*

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS

I think this api will help you with the SMS part of Android.

Comment: I think I have read that before writing my broadcast receiver code >_< however, +1 for "single SMS app" concept and NFC docs, it may get useful later.